# after npm audit fix in NODEJS app appeared the error 2 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

Tags: node.js, npm, localhost

How could I fix this error? its a nodejs application and everytime I do npm audit fix it gives me :
found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 moderate) in 330 scanned packages
  2 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.

what can I do to solve this?

```
                  === npm audit security report ===                        


                             Manual Review                                  
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
```

Moderate        Prototype Pollution

Package         lodash

Patched in      >=4.17.11

Dependency of   tedious-promises

Path            tedious-promises > lodash

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/782

Low             Prototype Pollution

Package         lodash

Patched in      >=4.17.5

Dependency of   tedious-promises

Path            tedious-promises > lodash

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577

Comment: you can `npm audit fix --force` or manually modify the package-lock.json to have versions that are not vulnerable.

Comment: update lodash to latest version something like `npm install lodash@latest --save`